# How do you check if space bar is pressed in animation loop? (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, animation, events

I have my animation loop:

```
function animate() {
    //draw every thing
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
animate();
```

That works fine, but how do I update it when the space bar is pressed?

I'm hoping for something like this:

```
function animate() {
    if (spacebar_pressed) {
        //draw something
    } else {
        //draw something else
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
animate();
```

I should also mention that only JavaScript answers are useful.

Comment: Can't you just use keypress event with JS? And how are you animating?

Comment: Try adding event listeners for [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/keydown) and [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/keyup) events, check if they are for the space bar and update a (boolean) variable to reflect the pressed state of the space bar. [`window.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with the `useCapture` parameter set should be useful to monitor the events. Catering for legacy browsers depends on the  target audience of your page.

Comment: @Traktor53, thanks! I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a boolean variable `spacebar_pressed` that is set to `false`. Set it to `true` when there is a keydown event and the key code is 32 (space bar). Set it to `false` when there is a keyup event where the key code is 32.

```
var spacebar_pressed = false;

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        spacebar_pressed = true;
    };
};
window.onkeyup = function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        spacebar_pressed = false;
    };
}

function animate() {
    if (spacebar_pressed) {
        //draw something
    } else {
        //draw something else
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};

animate();
```

It's important to note that Firefox doesn't support `event.keycode`, and instead uses `event.which`
Thank you @Traktor53 for your answer!